# How can I bind two delayed functions to a Button in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter, button, lambda, delayed-execution

```
from tkinter import *
    
def update():
    myEntry.config(bg="red")
def update2():
    myEntry.config(bg="blue")

root = Tk()
myEntry = Entry(root)
myEntry.pack()
myButton = Button(text="test", command=lambda: [myEntry.after(2000, update), myEntry.after(2000, update2)])
myButton.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

I tried to bind two delayed functions to a button, but only the second one works :(

Comment: If you have different delay values for the two functions, do they still not work?

Comment: The tkinter `.after` methods wait 2 seconds before the functions run.  They count the delays in parallel, not in series.  Both `update` functions run but within milliseconds of each other.

Answer (score 1):

Create a function, and call your delayed functions from that function. I'm going to assume you actually want the second function to happen 2 seconds after the first, so I've adjusted the time in the call to `after`.

```
def run_test():
    myEntry.after(2000, update)
    myEntry.after(4000, update2)
...
myButton = Button(text="test", command=run_test)
```

While you can use `lambda`, it makes the code harder to read and harder to debug, so I always recommend having a special-purpose function for callbacks whenever possible.